# When will camunda executeAsync() actually run

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, pcf

I am not clear how the executeAsync works in Camunda 7.15.0 version.

Using Java code in spring-boot application, I am trying to migrate few process instances from one process version to another using migration plan.

In java code when I use `execute()` method then the code is obviously executed immediately.

```
    import org.camunda.bpm.engine.RuntimeService;
                    
    final MigrationPlan migrationPlan = runtimeService.createMigrationPlan(fromProcessDefinitionId, toProcessDefinitionId).mapEqualActivities().build();
            
    final ProcessInstanceQuery processQuery = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().processDefinitionId(fromProcessDefinitionId); 
      
runtimeService.newMigration(migrationPlan).processInstanceQuery(processQuery).executeAsync();
```

But When I use `executeAsync()` method then I see the batch job waiting in the batches section but does not complete. How to know when will it execute?

Issue can be recreated in https://github.com/firstpostt/camunda-demo-migration. It needs postgres database and credentials need to be given in application.yml

There is an entry in act_ru_batch table. I don't see any entry in act_ru_job table

[image]

[image]

1. Can I configure in bpm-platform.xml file to make sure my migration plan runs within next 15 minutes when I use `executeAsync()` method?
2. Is there any option to force-trigger the batch from the admin cockpit when needed?

Comment: https://forum.camunda.org/t/batch-executeasync-does-not-start/29707

Comment: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/user-guide/process-engine/batch-operations/, https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/user-guide/process-engine/batch/, https://forum.camunda.org/t/migration-batch-does-not-complete/13861, https://camunda.com/blog/2019/10/job-executor-what-is-going-on-in-my-process-engine/, https://forum.camunda.org/t/batch-executeasync-for-camunda-migrationplan/29622/2, https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/reference/rest/migration/execute-migration-async/

Comment: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/reference/rest/case-execution/post-manual-start/, http://www.mianshigee.com/tutorial/camunda-docs-manual/173.md, https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/introduction/architecture/

Comment: https://forum.camunda.org/t/variable-data-is-not-loading-in-cockpit/15039/6

Comment: https://forum.camunda.org/t/camunda-variable-not-set-incase-of-error/29812/2

Comment: the issue sometimes occur in PCF but not in local machine. Try if increasing the memory allocated will make the job executor pickup the pending batches (camunda cockpit -> more -> batches).

Comment: If increasing the memory in PCF does not resolve the issue then only option is to deploy bare camunda version of application together wiith bpmn/dmn files i.e remove all the code except jackson etc configuration code, bpmn/dmn etc resources, pom.xml files, camunda migration classes and deploy it to PCF and this will probably work and execute the batch. from then onwards even after adding code the batch will probably work, if not then atleast the current batch issue is solved.

Comment: If you can remove data then remove all tables and create again without any data and camunda batch will work.

Comment: check this about `deployment-aware` which should be explicitly disabled even though camunda documentation says that the default value is false. https://forum.camunda.io/t/camunda-batch-not-running-in-pcf-application-because-acquisition-query-is-not-as-expected/40663/2

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The issue was with Postgres database but I am not sure what is the exact root cause because the issue is not easy to recreate. I dropped the database and created it again from scratch which seems to resolve the issue (I used the same sql scripts again using flyway so nothing changed w.r.t database schema. The only difference I can think of is that after some data is populated already into the tables then I created the unique constraint on camunda tables which might have caused the issue. Now I created unique constraint immediately before populating any data into the tables)

**P.S**:

I was using unique constraint in postgres Database https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/database/#additional-database-schema-configuration

I figured out that the issue was with database because I tried with h2 filesystem database(`camunda.bpm.database.schema-update` as true and `spring.datasource.url`=jdbc:h2:~/camunda;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false) and batch worked fine.

Then I used postgres database (without the unique constraint script) and batch worked fine. When I created a new database schema with the unique constraint script then the batch did not work and even if I dropped the constraint the batch did not work anymore

So I dropped the database and created a new database again without unique constraint and then the batch worked fine. After that I added the unique constraint and the batch still works fine.

I am not able to recreate the issue consistently but my guess is that it has something to do with the unique constraint. If you are not using this unique constraint then I am sure that this problem will never occur at all